# Rewrite rule for purl and querystrings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Whats is wrong with this rules?

RewriteEngine on

> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !&?n=[a-z]?
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www.)([a-z]+).myconsultinghouse.com$
>
> RewriteRule ^/$ /login.php?n=%1 [L,QSA]
>
> RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)?([^/]*)$ /$1.php?n=%1 [L,QSA] OR
>
> RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)?([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /$1.php?n=%1&et=$2 [L,QSA] OR
>
> RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)?([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /$1.php?n=%1&et=$2&ne=$3 [L,QSA]

I want be this:

If the user access the page - www.NameOfUser.domain.com/(NULL)

Redirect for /login.php?n=NameOfUser

If the user access the page - www.NameOfUser.domain.com/page

Redirect for /page.php?n=NameOfUser

If the user access the page - www.NameOfUser.domain.com/page/group

Redirect for /page.php?n=NameOfUser&et=group

If the user access the page - www.NameOfUser.domain.com/page/group/event

Redirect for /page.php?n=NameOfUser&et=group&ne=event

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Note:

- The `?` is not included in the query string.
- Conds only apply to the following rule but not subsequent.
- Query strings are not available in the rule match
- Since you don't have the leading `/` in the rule patterns, I assume that this is in the `DOCROOT/.htaccess` file and in this case you should set a base and use relative pathing in your replacement targets

so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}             ^www\.([a-z]+)\.myconsultinghouse\.com$
RewriteRule ^                        -                                [E=USER:%1]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}          \bn=[a-z]*\b                     [OR]
RewriteCond {%ENV:USER}              =""
RewriteRule ^                        -                                [S=4]

RewriteRule ^/$                      login.php?n=%{ENV:USER}          [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$             $1.php?n=%{ENV:USER}             [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(.*?)/?$       $1.php?n=%{ENV:USER}&et=$2       [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(.*?)/(.*?)/?$ $1.php?n=%{ENV:USER}&et=$2&ne=$3 [L,QSA]
```

This assumes that the username is `[a-z]+`.  You might also consider `\w+` if you want to allow digits and _

Comment: Now i need redirect if have nothing in url. So i will make what i wish :)... Thanks for help!

Comment: The main thing is clarity for _you_, so go with what you are comfortable.  But note `&?n=[a-z]+?` will match on "`n=&`"  and "`xxn=fred`".  That what the word boundary "`\b`" meta is for.  Use "`\bn=[a-z]*`" and replace the \* by a + if the name is mandatory.  Also the silent group operator "`(?:)`" is redundant if the bracket term is just plain text.  So `www.` is the same as `(?:www.)` but you need `www\.` because unescaped "`.`" matches any character.